# escape " double quotes" and slash (/) while variable substitution in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to escape "" and / for my VAR.
InFile contains below variable

```
var_value='"skdskdlskdlskjdlsdjsld/jshdks00=="' 
Echo ${var_value} 
"skdskdlskdlskjdlsdjsld/jshdks00=="
```

While substitution i do not want / and ""
I tried

```
sed "s#JWT=<<CHANGE_ME>>#"${JWT}"#g" InFile > OutFile
```

Expected OutFile :

```
JWT=skdskdlskdlskjdlsdjsld/jshdks00==
```

A help here would be much appreciated

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, I referred the link, however I want to substitute the ${VAR} in sed command, I am unable to do so by referring the mentioned link

Comment: Doesn't `sed 's#JWT=<<CHANGE_ME>>#"'"${JWT}"'"#g' InFile > OutFile` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, it's giving output in double quotes ""skdskdlskdlskjdlsdjsld/jshdks00==""

Comment: Then do not add the quotes - `sed 's#JWT=<<CHANGE_ME>>#'"${JWT}"'#g' InFile > OutFile`. The rule of concatenation explained in the linked post is still the same.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this isn't working as well. OutFile: "skdskdlskdlskjdlsdjsld/jshdks00=="

Comment: See `sed 's#JWT=<<CHANGE_ME>>#JWT='"${JWT}"'#g'` at https://ideone.com/tTgblm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242094/discussion-between-user15566016-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sh
sed 's#JWT=<<CHANGE_ME>>#JWT='"${JWT}"'#g' InFile > OutFile
```

Here, the concatenation scheme is the following:

```
's#JWT=<<CHANGE_ME>>#JWT='"${JWT}"'#g'
|------------------------||------||--|
             1               2      3
```

- `1` - single quoted part
- `2` - a double quoted string with interpolated variable
- `3` - single quoted part again.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/tTgblm):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
JWT="skdskdlskdlskjdlsdjsld/jshdks00=="
sed 's#JWT=<<CHANGE_ME>>#JWT='"${JWT}"'#g' <<< "JWT=<<CHANGE_ME>>"
## => JWT=skdskdlskdlskjdlsdjsld/jshdks00==
```